# How to replace JSF 1.2 with JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-1.2

I have an application, full application that made on JSF 1.2. Now we are adding module in it. Can i replace JSF 1.2 with JSF 2.0 ? Means only new module use JSF 2.0 and the remaining application become unaffected by the change? Means is JSF 2.0 is fully compatible with JSF 1.2. Like i open the project in netbeans and add JSF 2.0 jar in the project and remove the JSF 1.2 jar? Can i do that ? or i should have use JSF 1.2 for new module because application is made on JSF 1.2 ?

Thanks

Comment: There's [a pretty good thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0) for that here on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [a pretty good thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0) for that where they explain basic settings to more advanced settings to migrate from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0

Comment: One thing that is good for me is that i am just using JSF 1.2, no third party component. So i think, removing JSF 1.2 lib, adding JSF 2.0 lib, and changing root declaration web.xml and faces-config.xml is enough. Am i right? Really BalusC is genius....

Comment: It's been a while since I developed in JSF but i think it takes a lot more work than just editing web.xml and faces-config.xml. Agree, BalusC knows his stuff :)

Comment: hhmm ok thanks but at-least i'll give it a try. Actually i have made applications on JSF 2.0. Now i have to work on application that made on JSF 1.2 and this my first time that i use JSF 1.2, so i think it would be better for me if some how i manage the things using JSF 2.0 and Java is pretty good in backward compatibility... OK thanks for your help :)